# Raspberry Pi Imager sets the boot partition in read only mode

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-4, partition, readwrite

**Later Edit:** It seems there's an issue with the Imager on Linux Mint, although Mint is based on Ubuntu. Installing the OS using the command line [as described here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md) worked flawlessly

Current setup:

**Image Writer:** Raspberry Pi Imager 1.4 running on Linux Mint 20

**SD Card:** 64GB Adata

**Raspberry Pi:** Rasberry Pi 4 B. 4GB of RAM

**Image OS:** Raspbian Lite (no desktop enviroment)

**ISSUE:**

I'm trying to write the OS file on the SD card and enable the ssh via the ssh file in the boot partition.

However, when I try to create the ssh file in the boot partition, I get an error because the filesystem is read only.

Writing Ubuntu Server 20.10 to the same disk doesn't seem to have that issue. My feeling is that it has to do with the size of the disk as the same process on an old 8GB SD card seems to be working flawlesly.

I'm excluding a faulty SD card as formatting it using Mint's Gparted is making the card writable again.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: remount it read-write

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is not a problem of the image, or imager, or size of the SD Card. I think it is just a problem of the mount process with your Linux Mint 20 operating system. If the boot partition of the SD Card is mounted to `/mnt/` then you can try to remount it read/write:

```
mint ~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /mnt/
```